# Create a bootable ubuntu backup partition

Tags: grub2, backup, partitioning

This question is asked many times but I haven't got the right answer.

What I want is to create a partition where I backup my current Ubuntu partition that appears in the GRUB menu. If one day my Ubuntu won't to start I lunch the backup partition and *voila* my system is restored.

Currently I use CloneZilla but the problem is I must have always on me a usb key that contains CloneZilla.

EDIT:

```
df -h
/dev/sda5           55G     39G   14G  74% /
none               4,0K       0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev               997M    4,0K  997M   1% /dev
tmpfs              202M    1,2M  200M   1% /run
none               5,0M       0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none              1006M    8,0K 1006M   1% /run/shm
none               100M     36K  100M   1% /run/user
parted -l
nothing
```

Comment: Please print here `df -h` and `parted -l`.

Comment: here http://pastebin.com/ZwcqgD2y

Comment: I think that you don't know the right word: 'snapshot'. If you search with that you will find answers. Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/q/295426/62483

Comment: If no one write you answer in a few hours I will do it. Sorry can't do it write now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for note. There is many good methods that provide [backing up your system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem), some of them also provide incremental backups.

**Answering exactly what you want step by step**

As I can see from your `df -h` output, you do not distribute your `/boot`, `/usr`, `/var` and other folder to a different partitions. So

1.
First of all you should create your Live CD or bootable USB stick with Ubuntu. Here is guide for [Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) and for [USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

2.
Now boot Ubuntu from CD or USB, you should see a menu with **"Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer"** at the top. In loaded Ubuntu open `gnome-terminal` (Ctrl + Alt + T), and run `sudo gparted`. Create new 55Gb `ext4` partition using [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions) tutorial. Remember this new partition name, it should something like `/dev/sda6`.

3.
Now you should mount your new successfully created partition (Lets say `/dev/sda6`) and your previous partition `/dev/sda5`. And copy all your files and folders hierarchy. Open `gnome-terminal` and do this line by line:

```
sudo mkdir /media/old_partition
sudo mkdir /media/new_partition
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /media/old_partition
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/new_partition
sudo cp -ax /media/old_partition /media/new_partition
```

This last command can work very long. Do not interrupt it. It should output **nothing** at the end if everything is ok.

Little quote from [this guide](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Hard-Disk-Upgrade/copy.html).

***cp -ax / /new-disk***

*This is the simplest method, but will only work if your original Linux system is on a single disk partition.
The -a option preserves the original system as much as possible. The -x option limits cp to a single file system; this is necessary to avoid copying the /new-disk and /proc directories.*

4.
Now you need to update `fstab` in your new backup partition.

Find UUID of `/dev/sda6` (new partition):

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda6
```

Find UUID of `/dev/sda5` (old partition):

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda6
```

Then edit `/media/new_partition/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo gedit /media/new_partition/etc/fstab
```

And substitute UUID of `/dev/sda5` to UUID of `/dev/sda6`. **Be carefully, substitute only UUID**.

5.
Now adding new entry to grub menu. Open `/media/old_partition/etc/grub.d/40_custom` using `gedit` and add this at the 
end of the file:

```
menuentry "Boot backup Ubuntu" {
    set root=UUID=XXXX-YYYY
        linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=XXXX-YYYY ro quiet splash
            initrd /initrd.img
    }
```

Where XXXX-YYYY is UUID of new partition (`/dev/sda6`).

6.
Unmount everything and reboot. Before do this **close everything** what you have opened (`gparted`, `gnome-terminal`, `gedit`, others).

```
sudo umount /dev/sda5
sudo umount /dev/sda6
sudo reboot
```

Remove your LIVE bootable device.

Now you should see new entry in your grub boot menu.

Notice that this method do not backing up other than `/` mount points, such as `/home`, `/var`, `/usr` others, if they distributed between partitions. In such situation you should do steps 2-4 for each partition.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain here step by step, but you should be able to finish with this explanation!

Firstly, create a partition, that is big enough.
Then, copy your ubuntu installation to this partition, remaining the file attributes.
Create the entry in grub, by copying and adjusting the partition id.
I guess now you only have to edit fstab on the new partition.

So easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You even don't need a separate partition, you can move your whole system to a subfolder then add a a grub menuentry to boot into it. I just posted how to do it in different thread, check out my answer named kenn here [Installing Multiple Linux Distros in a single partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405735/installing-multiple-linux-distros-in-a-single-partition)